# Elegant way to wrap multiple Backbone render methods to avoid "before" and "after" event duplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I've divided the `render()` method on my View into two separate methods, in order to allow me to render the entire View, or just a small portion of the View, which is represented by an HTML form. The two `render()` methods look as such:

```
    render: function () {
        var templateData = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes, localizedText),
            compiledLoadStopTemplate = Handlebars.compileClean(template);

        this.isClosed = false;

        this.triggerMethod("before:render", this);
        this.triggerMethod("item:before:render", this);

        this.$el.html(compiledLoadStopTemplate(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(templateData))));
        this.renderAppointmentForm();

        this.bindUIElements();

        this.showStatusNotification();

        this.triggerMethod("render", this);
        this.triggerMethod("item:rendered", this);

        return this;
    },
    renderAppointmentForm: function () {
        var templateData = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes, localizedText, { notification: this.notification }),
            compiledAppointmentFormTemplate = Handlebars.compileClean(appointmentFormTemplate);

        this.triggerMethod("before:render", this);
        this.triggerMethod("item:before:render", this);

        this.$el.find(".hook-appointment-form-container").html(compiledAppointmentFormTemplate(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(templateData))));

        this.bindUIElements();

        this.showStatusNotification();

        this.triggerMethod("render", this);
        this.triggerMethod("item:rendered", this);

        return this;
    },
```

Now, there's obviously a boatload of duplicated code here; while the template data, template, and actual `html()` call are unique, almost all of the other lines are common between them.

It'd be nice to have a wrapped method that would allow me to supply the template data, compiled template, and `html()` lines, and automatically have the rest of the other before/after-firing methods in place universally, but I couldn't devise a method using Underscore's `wrap()` that really worked.

I'm sure there's a more advanced programming concept that fits this need perfectly, but it's avoiding my grasp right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about extracting form in separate view? If its not possible then I have this suggestion:

```
loadStopTemplate: Handlebars.compileClean(template),

appointmentFormTemplate: Handlebars.compileClean(appointmentFormTemplate),

getTemplateAttributes: function () {
    var attributes = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes, localizedText, { notification: this.notification });
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributes))
},

render: function () {
    this.isClosed = false;
    return this.enterRenderState(function (attributes) {
        this.$el.html(this.loadStopTemplate(attributes));
        this._renderForm(attributes);
    })
},

renderAppointmentForm: function () {
    return this.enterRenderState(this._renderForm)
},

_renderForm: function (attributes) {
    this.$('.hook-appointment-form-container')
        .html(this.appointmentFormTemplate(attributes))
    return this;
},

enterRenderState: function (callback) {
    this.triggerMethod("before:render", this);
    this.triggerMethod("item:before:render", this);
    callback.call(this, this.getTemplateAttributes());
    this.bindUIElements();
    this.showStatusNotification();
    this.triggerMethod("render", this);
    this.triggerMethod("item:rendered", this);
    return this
}
```

Comment: I think I prefer this approach to Jack's. Clever use of callback to pass in template data, nice utilization of a pseudo-private method to eliminate redundant code execution without needing a switch statement or some sort of goofy if-else. The only change I'd make is getting rid of the top-level properties for the templates, as they're only really referenced a single time within the render methods themselves. Otherwise, I like it a lot, so thanks!

Comment: @J.KyMarsh for what's worth I would probably also go with this approach, I didn't spend that much time thinking about how to refactor your code.

Comment: The purpose of keeping templates in prototype is to avoid the need of compiling them multiple times per render. This way they are compiled and cached.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can easily refactor this is by creating a helper function that does all of the common functionality and then just pass in some functions for the parts that are different.

For example

```
render: function () { 
var templateData = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes, localizedText),
        compiledLoadStopTemplate = Handlebars.compileClean(template);
    var self = this;

    var isClosed = function () {
        self.isClosed = false;
    }

    var renderHTML = function () {

     self.$el.html(compiledLoadStopTemplate(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(templateData))));

    }

    return this.renderHelper(renderHTML, isClosed);
}

renderAppointmentForm: function () {

       var templateData = _.extend({}, this.model.attributes, localizedText, { notification: this.notification }),
        compiledAppointmentFormTemplate = Handlebars.compileClean(appointmentFormTemplate);

    var renderHTML = function () {
        self.$el.find(".hook-appointment-form-container").html(compiledAppointmentFormTemplate(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(templateData))));
    }

    return this.renderHelper(renderHTML);
}


renderHelper: function (renderHTML, isClosed) {

    if (isClosed) {
        isClosed();
    }

    this.triggerMethod("before:render", this);
    this.triggerMethod("item:before:render", this);

    renderHTML();

    this.triggerMethod("render", this);
    this.triggerMethod("item:rendered", this);

    return this;

}
```

Comment: This was my backup approach; not a bad solution, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant. Also, my original render() also calls renderAppointmentForm(); using either my original approach or yours, this means that all the logic shared between the two renders would be called twice. Any ideas on what to do about that?